# Copyright information for android dev guide

Tags: android

looking for a link to the copyright information for android dev guide.  I have been told prior that their guide is in the public domain and I want to see if thats true.  Plus one of the books I have read was almost a straight copy and paste from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each documentation has following footer.

> Except as noted, this content is licensed under Apache 2.0. For details and restrictions, see the Content License.

http://developer.android.com/license.html says:

> Exact Reproductions
>
> If your online work exactly reproduces text or images from this site, in whole or in part, please include a paragraph at the bottom of your page that reads:
>
> Portions of this page are reproduced from work created and shared by the Android Open Source Project and used according to terms described in the Creative Commons 2.5 Attribution License.
>
> Also, please link back to the original source page so that readers can refer there for more information.